# How to fix 'imageNamed:' error

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, uiimageview

I am trying to create a program that will randomly generate a photo. I am using this code to do so:

```
    int imageSwitch = rand() % 2;

switch (imageSwitch) {
    case 0:
        Picture.image = [UIImageView imageNamed:@"8292.jpg"];
        break;

    case 1:
        Picture.image = [UIImageView imageNamed:@"apple sauce.jpg"];

    default:
        break;
```

However, I always get the same error about `imageNamed:`, which is "No known class method for selector 'imageNamed:'"
Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: When you get an error like this, lookup the method in the reference documentation. Here you have clearly seen the method is from `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView`. If you can't find the method, look at the class. You may have been trying to use a method with the wrong name.

Answer (score 1):

`imageNamed:` is a class method of `UIImage`, not `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

`imageNamed:` is an class method of `UIImage`, so you need to do

```
int imageSwitch = rand() % 2;

switch (imageSwitch) {
   case 0:
      Picture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"8292.jpg"];
      break;

   case 1:
      Picture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple sauce.jpg"];
      break;
default:
    break;
```